# Adding question to a post.

Tags: discussion, etiquette, asking-questions

There are some cases when users ask a specific question in their post and then after receiving an answer addressing their question,they edit their post with more than 2 or 3 questions which are not so similar to the original question.

Personally I think that this is an irritating habit of these users and also if someone wants to ask additional questions then I believe that he/she can ask them in different posts.

Not in the same post after receiving an answer for their first original question.

What is your opinion about that?

Is this something that must be prevented or am I exaggerating?

Thank you in advance and excuse me for my bad English.

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, then this is related on main meta: [Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478)

Comment: Maybe..this is my first question on meta

Comment: This was discussed here a few times. Some posts which I was able to find quickly:
[question edited to change meaning](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2304) (and the posts [linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/2304)),
[Should I delete my answer after OP changed his/her question in an essential way?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25489),
[Changing the question and invalidating previous answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26022),
[Editing a question after receiving one or more answers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26565).

Comment: You're right: when abused, this is irritating and they should probably be formulating new posts.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Two points to start:

- Ideally question posts should  be in final form when first posted. If everything goes according to plan no change at all needs to be made. Of course, some modifications and clarifications can be alright and desirable. Yet still the idea is that a question is posted in final form. (As opposed to the idea being that a question-post and an answer-post in some kind of symbiosis over several rounds of edits are grown to more complete forms.)
  In particular, edits to a questions should not make existing answers invalid or incomplete.
- As a rule "not so similar [...] question[s]" should never be in the same question post, not even when posted at the same time. The idea is more "one question per post" (not to be taken absolutely literally, but to get the idea across).

As a consequences of this what you describe is a malpractice for at least two distinct reasons. It should be avoided. Don't be shy to enforce it.

How you go about this is a matter of style. One way is to explain to OP that what they do may be a disservice to themselves. For example, like this:

> I noticed you edited your post to include additional questions that are somewhat distinct from the original one. Posting them as a new post instead might give them more visibility. Moreover, users that have already provided answers here may be frustrated by their answers being rendered incomplete.

However, with users that are not susceptible to reason and do this repeatedly one might just rollback their edit to the original version.

As always there is some gray-area. What I wrote above applies to a situation of adding new and especially somewhat unrelated questions (well) after the original was asked and answered. If it is just a small complementary question motivated by an answer and no-one minds, it can be alright to add it. Yet even then, in case of conflict, the original post needs to stand and a new post should be asked.

Comment: Your suggested text is very good. I intend to use it in future if I see myself in the situation described here.

Comment: I think another way to come at it is that editing it too much could render you less reputable because you probably won't gain the reputation that asking the distinct questions separately will.